# for loop skips like 10 steps

Tags: java, for-loop, grid

EDIT: Answered.

I'm trying to create a grid for a maze generation algorithm (Recursive backtracker) here's my code (`c` = the number of columns and `r` = the number of rows)

```
for(int x = 1; x <= c; x++){
    for(int y = 1; y <= r; y++){
        cells.put(x + "-" + y, new Cell(x, y));
        System.out.println("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine except the loops skips some lines example it goes from `x=1` to `x=11` without doing `x=2,x=3,x=4` etc. It just goes `x=1,x=11`
here is a debug log: http://pastebin.com/FDfTtWYq its rather long so I posted in on pastebin.

NOTE: this only happens when there are `25+` rows and columns.

Comment: Your loop is working totally fine, so the problem is caused somewhere else, could you share your whole source code with us?

Comment: This is really weird. The loops look fine (and should iterate over everything). Where are you logging the output? what is cells? On what OS (and device) are you running the program?

Comment: Cell basically stores a x and y value and has some methods. I log it in the console (eclipse)

Comment: warning your loops should start from `1` or the test should be strict I mean `x < c` otherwise you will get `c + 1` columns and `r + 1` rows

Comment: I've updated the code. This is the only line where I modify cells.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip, ill change it and test it.

Comment: Your text refers to variable `i` but the code uses `x` and `y`... why?

Comment: Oh thats because I've changed it around. I'll update the text.

Comment: Looking at you log: the only iteration that is complete is the i = 0, then i = 1 y reaches 20 only. You have problems on y too

Comment: I did what Nicolas Filotto said and it's working now. Thanks!